# Is Hitting SOQL Limits Inevitable with Large Volume/Complex Flows?

Tags: visual-workflow, governorlimits

I want to know if there is anything I can do to prevent hitting query limits when executing a rather complex, large volume flow. Here are the details:

1. Solution Context: Data synchronization to update and create parent-child records (Contact and Contact Role_c). I know data transformation is best handled outside of SF in ETL...but no money.
2. Solution Config: Process Builder, Master Flow, Subflow
3. Number of total elements (record lookup, record create): 30; 2/14/14 - Does not include non-bulkifiable elements (i.e. decisions)
4. Desired Number of records processed: 4,000+
5. Execution schedule: every day or every other day

I have heard that using fast elements and loops can help reduce the number of queries, but with the volume and complexity I am working with, will it even make a difference?

Any input is highly appreciated. If limits are unavoidable, we will most likely reduce the number of records processed to about 100 max to avoid hitting limits. We have no developers and have resorted to flow/process builder for this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, flows are particularly ill-suited for performing bulk ETL. Flows have particular limits that make it impractical to work with more than a couple of hundred records. You'll want to read more about the limits in [Limits for Visual Workflow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_admin_flow_limits.htm), but the most notable limit is:

> Maximum number of executed elements at run time   2,000

So, let's say you have a loop where you're using an assignment module to set a field in a SObject Collection. If you have more than 2,000 rows in the collection, you will hit this governor limit, without exception.

It's hard to even build a flow that doesn't violate either the DML limit or the SOQL limit, but given the *additional* limits specific to flows, it's impossible to do any bulk processing that you'd do with a simple batchable class.

Comment: I have used invocable classes called from flows to help get around this, but I think that ultimately the limits will make using a fully coded solution inevitable in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I have decided to narrow the scope of records evaluated to about 50 or less for each execution. The flow passed the test for 2,700 records and still testing for 4000+ records. My concern that is while the flows only evaluate 50 or so records, the process that launches the flows still performs a simple validation on all 4000 records. Hoping that is not an issue in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

We had a recent requirement and when we checked with salesforce and they confirmed that flows are not bulkified. So better option is to write an apex class and bulkify it.